# Refresh a JFrame after submitting

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a JForm/`JFrame` that I want to be refreshed or reload after a user submits a form. But window does not close. Only refresh the JForm is `repaint()` is right solution or any other.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What happens when the user submits (I suppose you mean that the user presses some kind of "OK" button)? In a proper MVC pattern, your views listen for changes in the model and each view knows how to react/update itself according to model notifications. Repaint may work in some case (if for example you overrode paintComponent), in some others it may not, you may have to call revalidate before, and there are other cases...

Comment: when user hit enter it saves record in database and i want refresh the form for next entry but form does not close

Answer (score 0):

No no. Using the repaint() is a bad way of doing things. You can use dialog boxes or open another JFrame (after closing/using setVisible(false) the current one), etc.
Extend your question and I could help you better.

**Edit**

You can call a method that updates the form after the submit button has been pressed. You can use repaint() in the end if you need to.

Comment: I want to save the records from same frame in database with different user... when 1st record is saved in database then I dont want to close that form and enter 2nd record. only form is refreshed but not closed..how can i do this

Comment: It's best you use JDialog s for your work. Set the JDailog in a JFrame and keep on creating a new JDialog when the data entry is over

Comment: yes I do this but form is not refreshed..when I enter 2nd record I want to run the file again and enter the 2nd record but I dont want to do this..I have the form is still open to enter the number of record  at same time

Comment: Why would repaint be a bad way of doing things? You can perfectly have a component that automatically updates itself just by calling repaint(). Anyway, the question is too vague to be answered currently

Comment: @ Guillaume Polet yes I guess you are right, repaint() would be useful in that case

Comment: one more question please can I ask u?

Comment: @Jayashri please edit your question and make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

if your are add a new components or removing components from Jframe after submitting

you can use the 
    "revalidate();"
with the component example

```
actionPerformed(ActionListener a)
{
JButton b=new JButton("xyz");
frame.add(b);
b.revalidate();

}
```